# how many rep points are awarded on SO per day?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, site-stats

I'm just curious about the stats for the site as a whole.

How many questions are asked per day? How many rep points are earned per day? That sort of thing.

I presume the numbers are increasing over time as the site becomes more well known. Does that mean that there's ever likely to be any pressure to change the thresholds for some of the badges?

Hmm.. I seem to have asked several questions at once there. But hopefully you'll be able to see where I'm going with my train of thought.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com